# Save to Foursquare button doesn't work on iPad

Tags: ios, foursquare

I'm trying to build an "Save to Foursquare" button to my site, but it doesn't work on an iPad.  In fact, I checked and none of the sites that use this button work on the iPad - pressing the button just darkens the display but doesn't show the Foursquare dialog.  Is there a fix for this?

Comment: What version of iOS / iPad? It works fine for me on an iPad clicking the button on nymag.com sites.

Comment: iOS 5.0.1, I checked nymag.com and the same thing happens - press the button results in a darkened web page, but no foursquare dialogue.

Answer (score 0):

We just pushed an improvement to handling the save-to-foursquare button on iOS. Hopefully that should fix whatever problem you were hitting?